# Datatables Find Replace If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

How do I do a find/replace on specific elements in a datatable? I'm trying to replace elements in the table with font awesome icons:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
  $('td').html().replace('0', '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>');
  $('td').html().replace('1', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>');
} );
```

JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wo02xedr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some bit of your code is wrong, Here you go..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();  
    $("td").each(function() {
   $(this).html( $(this).html().replace('0', '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>').replace('1', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>'));

});
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/wo02xedr/2/

Comment: Thanks @FREAKENGINEER. How do I just do it on one table? When I put a table object in instead of "td" it doesn't like it: http://jsfiddle.net/wo02xedr/9/

Comment: You can not iterate thorugh #example, Their is just one element having id "example"..

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the text and replace using the `old` parameter:

```
$('td').text(function (i, old) {
    $(this).html(old.replace('0', '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>').replace('1', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>'))
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyyab1co/)

Comment: Some issue with your jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1):

I see some improvements :

1. first you should loop on each element by using `$("td").each(function() {...})`
2. update the html of your `td`s (here you only read it) with : `$this.html(...)`

This gives something like this :

```
$('td').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.html($this.html()
        .replace('0', '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>')
        .replace('1', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i>'));
});
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wo02xedr/8/